# How to display full datetime value in Visual Studio 2017 "View Data" grid?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Let's say I have a SQL Server database table where one of the columns is of type `datetime`.

Let's say actual value in database is `2019-04-20 12:55:21.550`

If I go to SQL Server Object Explorer tab, right-click on the table and select "View Data" the value displayed in the grid is `4/20/2019 12:55:21 PM`. The problem is that fraction of a second is not displayed and I can't edit it.

Is there a way to change that behavior so that `datetime` values are displayed as `2019-04-20 12:55:21.550` and is also editable as such?

**Clarification**: I know I can edit values with an `UPDATE` statement. I want to know if there is a way to configure Visual Studio to use a different format for this grid.

Comment: Dates have no format, they are binary values. Client applications apply a format when they display them as text, eg in a grid, form, label. What you see is the format used by SSMS/Visual Studio, nothing more

Comment: The best way by far to edit this data is with an update statement.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't use the GUI to edit the data. If you need to, use a proper `UPDATE` statement, or (if it's an application you're creating), ensure that you set up your application to provide the correct display format for the data. Data, in SQL Server, is nothing other than binary values, and dates don't have a format attached to them. The values `'20190101'` and `2019-01-01T00:00:000.000` would appear exactly the same from a binary point of view, if then column is a `datetime`.

Comment: I realize I can edit them with an update. I would like to know if it is possible to configure Visual Studio to use a different format for the grid.

Comment: Of course you can use a different format. You use the string format on the column.

Comment: Where can I specify string format for that?